# Can i make changes to a file in maven builded without building it again?

Tags: maven, jboss

I am having a maven project where it will build and run through JBOSS. But every time I make a change in any of the project files, I have to build the whole code again which will give a .war file. Is there a way to change the files without having to build the code again?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please extend your question incl. which java version, maven version and/or framework you are using? Have you considered splitting code in modules, and re-building per-module?

Answer (score 2):

No.

There may be a way to test your code changes without running a full Maven build, but you cannot change the resulting WAR without rebuilding it.